# as3 air on android - transparent over jpg background bug?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

Details: Device (Xoom, latest OS) with Air (latest prerelease), JPG is a 8bit RGB. Built in FlashDevlop (latest with a android project).

Example: http://ryanmills.net/zips/overlay_bug.jpg

I am using the latest prerelease air runtime and im running into a strange bug.I cant put anything with a transparent background over an embed jpg. I have tried this with PNG's, TextFields and Input TextFields. All of them have its slight outline over an embed JPG (RGB/8bit).

You can see where the input textfield is slightly longer and going off the side of white background sprite. Same exact thing happens with text in a png24 with a transparent background. You get this sort of slightly alpha background. However if I overlay it on a solid colored sprite its just fine. Its only over the embed JPG (RGB/8bit). Using the latest FlashDevlop with an android project.

Can anyone confirm this is a bug in the prerelease or a common issue with AIR on android? Or did I make a mistake somewhere? Cant seem to find a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this is a known bug in the beta with alpha ch. work around is using a PNG.